# How to add delay to a subtask in a group in celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

My workflow is this: I've a group of subtasks and each task should be executed at certain intervals but none of them should happen at the same time.

I tried this:

```
celery.group(getting_a_page.s(user,x,page).countdown(x) for x in range(5))
```

But that didn't work.

Any idea how to do this? There isn't much about this on docs. I can delay a task but not a subtask according to the docs.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.subtask()` has the following Parameters:

- task – Either a task class/instance, or the name of a task.
- args – Positional arguments to apply.
- kwargs – Keyword arguments to apply.
- options – Additional options to `Task.apply_async()`.

Task.apply_async() has options: countdown and eta which can be used to set delays

Hence you can do something like:

```
celery.group(getting_a_page.s(args=(user, x, page), countdown=X))
# where X is any number
```

Read More [Here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html?highlight=subtask#celery.subtask)

Comment: I get an error:  got an unexpected keyword argument 'countdown'

Comment: try `options={countdown:x}`

Comment: The above won't work, at least not anymore. The other way to do this is to do `my_task.s().set(countdown=10)`

Comment: @mlissner, it would be good to write a new answer, stating how its done for  latest celery version

Comment: This won't help, [countdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) just sets the "earliest time at which your task will be executed". So they could happen at the same time.